# How to Split MP3 Files with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to split mp3 files with FFmpeg into the small mp3 files make it easy to manage, share and transfer ?
For example , I do have test.mp3 file with 1MB and I want to split into test00(i).mp3 files with smaller size.

I've tried with windows tool but want to have script which is running with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is brief article.

https://windowsloop.com/split-mp3-files-with-ffmpeg/

Actually you can use ffmpeg script like below.

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp3" -f segment -segment_time 3600 -c copy
test%00d.mp3
```

-i test.mp3 means your input file and

test%00d.mp3 will be your output files.

if you want one-minute chunks, then you should replace 3600 with 60.